# In GitAhead, it is not possible to create a new branch with upstream

Tags: git, branch, gitahead

With the command Branch | Neuer Branch ... a GitAhead Window appears an I can enter the Name of the new Branch. The pull down menu does not allow me to enter my desired starting point (select master?). The upstream pull down menu does also not allow to enter the branch name like "origin/new_Branch. Where can I find the instructions, how to create a new branch?
There is no chance to enter "origin/newbranch" - the pulldown menu do not offer "newbranch" and it is not possible to type in the name. 
Thank you
Bahne

Answer (score 1):

When clicking on starting point you'll have branches|remotes|tags, choose your starting point and do not select an upstream. When using "pushing to", you can choose your newly created branch after doiing commits then use "set upstream". It will create you new origin/newbranch.